# How to parse specific field from GMAIL body to google SHEETS

Tags: regex, gmail, gmail-api

I have a gmail body that starts with this:

```
Name: Full Report
Store: River North (Wells St)
Date Tripped: 18 Feb 2020 8:40 PM
Business Date: 18 Feb 2020 (Closed)
Message:
Information:
This alert was tripped based on a user defined trigger: Every 5 minutes.
```

I'm trying to parse the Date Tripped: field and the Business Date: field but don't believe i'm getting the regex correct.

```
    // Implement Parsing rules using regular expressions
    if (content) {

      tmp = content.match(/Date Tripped: \s*([A-Za-z0-9.\s ]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var tripped = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'N/A';

      tmp = content.match(/Business Date: \[0-9][()]/);
      var businessdate = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'N/A';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Date Tripped, minor change needed:

```
Date Tripped:\s*([:A-Za-z0-9\s]+)\r?\n
```

Your main error: you forgot to put `:` inside the class brackets.
Tip: get rid of the `(` and `)` around `\r?\n`. You don't want to catch those.

You could make this even a bit shorter:

```
Date Tripped:\s*([:\w\s]+)\r?\n
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JtfJnZ/4)

For the business date, this one will do:

```
Business Date:\s([\w\s]+\([a-zA-Z]+\))
```

Or even shorter:

```
Business Date:\s([\w\s]+\(\w+\))
```

Your (main) error: you escape `\[` which is not correct here. Next: `[()]` matches `(` and `)`, but not `(Closed)`.
See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AS4Jde/3)

Comment: The 'Date Tripped:' field is working with this now, thank you.  The 'Business Date:' field is still not working, your expression posts the following error on regex101
/
Business Date:\s[\w\s]+\(\w+)
/
gm
All the errors detected are listed below, from left to right, as they appear in the pattern.
) Unmatched parenthesis

Comment: Sorry, typo. Corrected. The `(` and `)` should be both escaped.

Comment: Thanks, I get the Full Match with that but not the group which would report '18 Feb 2020 (Closed)'

Comment: Then you need to capture it by putting it between `(` and `)`. I'll adapt the example.

Comment: I get it now, thanks for your assistance.  Working.

Comment: Is there a way to make this search for these fields in only the first 6 lines of the email?
I'm noticing the script execution time has gone way up due to the body of the email having so much content.

Comment: Posted an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307163/how-to-restrict-matches-to-the-first-5-lines-of-an-email-body-using-regex-in-gas/60313393#60313393

Answer (score 1):

You could also make the pattern a bit more specific and use a single pattern to match both options.

```
\b(?:Business Date|Date Tripped):\s*(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])\s+[A-Za-z]+\s+\d{4}\s+(?:\([^()]+\)|(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5]?[0-9]\s*[AP]M)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b(?:Business Date|Date Tripped):\s*` Match one of the options
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]` Match a digit 1-31
- `)` Close group
- `\s+[A-Za-z]+\s+\d{4}\s+` Match 1+ char A-Za-z followed by 4 digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\([^()]+\)` Match from an openining parenthesis till closing parenthesis
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5]?[0-9]\s*[AP]M` Match a time pattern
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RCV8rJ/1)

Note that that pattern does not validate the date itself.