# How to restrict matches to the first 5 lines of an email body using regex in GAS

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using the following script which is working correctly to pull 2 fields out of an email body.

This is causing the script execution time to increase significantly due to the amount of content in the body. Is there a way to make this search through only the first 5 lines of the email body?

First lines of e-mail:

```
Name: Full Report
Store: River North (Wells St)
Date Tripped: 19 Feb 2020 1:07 PM
Business Date: 19 Feb 2020 (Open)
Message:
Information:
This alert was tripped based on a user defined trigger: Every 15 minutes.
```

Script:

```
//gets first(latest) message with set label
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('South Loop').getThreads(0,1);
if (threads && threads.length > 0) {
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  // Get the first email message of a threads
  var tmp,
    subject = message.getSubject(),
    content = message.getPlainBody();
  // Get the plain text body of the email message
  // You may also use getRawContent() for parsing HTML

  // Implement Parsing rules using regular expressions
  if (content) {

    tmp = content.match(/Date Tripped:\s*([:\w\s]+)\r?\n/);
    var tripped = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'N/A';

    tmp = content.match(/Business Date:\s([\w\s]+\(\w+\))/);
    var businessdate = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'N/A';
  }
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice, with example input and what should be matched, but you can get the first 5 lines of a string using `content.match(/(?:.*\n){0,5}/)` and then run your search regex on that.

Comment: @ggorlen Having trouble implementing that correctly, I updated with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: content = message.getPlainBody();

Comment: Updated example, I'll work on a runnable snippet.

Comment: They are guaranteed to exist, i just put N/A in case the script fails. This is google apps script.  The script is working fine, just the execution time is very high.

Comment: Ah, of course, your post is tagged accordingly... a runnable snippet is not necessary. This is good, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could get the first 5 lines using another pattern `^.*(?:\r?\n.*){4}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the pattern `/^(?:.*\r?\n){0,5}/` to grab the first 5 lines of the email, then run your search against this smaller string. Here's a browser example with hardcoded `content`, but I tested it in Google Apps Script.

```js
const Logger = console; // Remove this for GAS!

const content = `Name: Full Report
Store: River North (Wells St)
Date Tripped: 19 Feb 2020 1:07 PM
Business Date: 19 Feb 2020 (Open)
Message:
Information:
This alert was tripped based on a user defined trigger: Every 15 minutes.`;

const searchPattern = /(Date Tripped|Business Date): *(.+?)\r?\n/g;
const matches = [...content.match(/^(?:.*\r?\n){0,5}/)[0]
                           .matchAll(searchPattern)]

const result = Object.fromEntries(matches.map(e => e.slice(1)));
Logger.log(result);
```

If you wish to dynamically inject the search terms, use:

```js
const Logger = console; // Remove this for GAS!

const content = `Name: Full Report
Store: River North (Wells St)
Date Tripped: 19 Feb 2020 1:07 PM
Business Date: 19 Feb 2020 (Open)
Foo: this will match because it's on line 5
Bar: this won't match because it's on line 6
Information:
`;

const searchTerms = ["Date Tripped", "Business Date", "Foo", "Bar"];
const searchPattern = new RegExp(`(${searchTerms.join("|")}): *(.+?)\r?\n`, "g");
const matches = [...content.match(/^(?:.*\r?\n){0,5}/)[0]
                           .matchAll(searchPattern)]

const result = Object.fromEntries(matches.map(e => e.slice(1)));
Logger.log(result);
```

ES5 version if you're using the older engine:

```js
var Logger = console; // Remove this for GAS!

var content = "Name: Full Report\nStore: River North (Wells St)\nDate Tripped: 19 Feb 2020 1:07 PM\nBusiness Date: 19 Feb 2020 (Open)\nMessage:\nInformation:\nThis alert was tripped based on a user defined trigger: Every 15 minutes.\n";

var searchPattern = /(Date Tripped|Business Date): *(.+?)\r?\n/g;
var truncatedContent = content.match(/^(?:.*\r?\n){0,5}/)[0];
var result = {};

for (var m; m = searchPattern.exec(content); result[m[1]] = m[2]);

Logger.log(result);
```

Comment: Note to op: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Comment: Thanks for that note. I'm a total apps script novice, so I can add an ES5 version if needed.

Comment: Google will automatically force upgrade sooner/later. I don't think a es5 version is needed. Cheers.

Comment: @ggorlen I've updated my post to show current code, seems the execution time is the same unfortunately.  Perhaps i'm executing this inefficiently or there's no way to only read the first 5 lines of the body?

Comment: Yeah--the emails would have to be enormous for this to matter, so you probably incorrectly identified the bottleneck originally. Moving the goalpost by drastically altering a question after asking it and accepting an answer is frowned upon. I recommend rolling back to your original question and opening a new question that shows the latest code and asks where the bottleneck is and how to fix it. When you do, please include closing `}` so that your code is free of syntax errors and others don't need to work just to get it to run. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen the regex you mentioned does *not* grab the first 5 lines of a string. I've posted an answer to prove my statement and to explain why.

Comment: OK, my plaintext didn't match my code. There should be a `^` anchor at the beginning. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I agree I should have removed the default multiline and global settings on regex101. My bad. However, I still think your regex is wrong because it matches empty lines. See https://regex101.com/r/hUpr8u/5

Comment: This was intentional. If there's a blank line among the first 5 lines, it doesn't make sense to reject the match. If you use `.+` you get nothing. Maybe not anchoring it with `(.+\r?\n){0,5}` is better... I can add that.

Comment: The regex is fundamentally not wrong, though, these are little tweaks/assumptions about handling edge cases that OP never mentioned existed.

Answer (score -1):

@ggorlen's answer is not precise, to my taste. Let's have a look at [regex01](https://regex101.com/r/hUpr8u/5)

My problem with `(?:.*\r?\n){0,5}` is this: in english this regex says:

```
Take any number of characters (0 or more) ending with a newline. 
Do this between 0 and 5 times.
```

Which means *any* empty string matches. If you would do a global match, there's a lot of those.

So, how could you grab the first 5 lines? *Be exact!* So something like

```
^([^\r\n]+\r?\n){5}
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hUpr8u/4)

**P.S.** @ggorlen mentioned I left the default multiline matching on in regex101, and he's right about that. Your preference may vary: choosing between ignoring messages with less than 5 lines and accepting strings with empty lines depends on your particular case.

**P.S.2** I've adapted my wording and disabled the multiline and global settings in regex101 to display my concerns with it.

Comment: This destroys/misinterprets my regex by adding a multiline flag and removing the beginning of string anchor and offers a more brittle substitute. OP's performance issue clearly has nothing to do with this regex, it's a lot of heavy usage of Google app script library calls that are only shown in a previous edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I used the regex in the top of your answer. Which does not contain the caret.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion then. I didn't copy it correctly from my code. All 3 code snippets use the correct version, so this is a typo on my part.